# Single adapter for multiple recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I wanted to use a single adapter for multiple RecyclerView sharing the same layout design. I made a custom class which includes my 3 ArrayList for text, picture and audio and I am inserting resources from different fragments in my custom class.

Adapter Class:

```js
package com.example.adil.tabpen;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.adil.tabpen.Fragment.TwoFragment;
import com.example.adil.tabpen.OurData;

/**
 * Created by Adil on 10/2/2017.
 */

public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        return new ListViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        ((ListViewHolder) holder).bindView(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return OurData.title.size();
    }

    private class ListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
    {
        private TextView text;
        private ImageView image;
        private ImageButton button;

        public ListViewHolder(View itemview)
        {
            super(itemview);
            text = (TextView) itemview.findViewById(R.id.textF);
            image = (ImageView) itemview.findViewById(R.id.imageF);
            button = (ImageButton) itemview.findViewById(R.id.button);
            itemview.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        public void bindView(final int position)
        {
            text.setText(OurData.title.get(position));
            image.setImageResource(OurData.pic.get(position));
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(v.getContext(), OurData.record.get(position));
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                }
            });
        }

        public void onClick (View view)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

1st Fragment (small letter):

```js
package com.example.adil.tabpen.Fragment;

import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.adil.tabpen.Adapter;
import com.example.adil.tabpen.ListAdapter;
import com.example.adil.tabpen.OurData;
import com.example.adil.tabpen.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class OneFragment extends Fragment
{
    public OneFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<String> players;
    ArrayList<Integer> images;

    //String [] players = {"Tamim","Shakib","Mashrafe","Ashraful"};
    //int [] images = {R.drawable.a,R.drawable.b,R.drawable.c,R.drawable.a};

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

        //Built-in adapter
        /*String[] menuItem = {"Hello","Hi","Bye"};
        ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        ArrayAdapter<String> listViewAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                menuItem
        );
        listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);*/

        //Custom adapter
        /*listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        players = new ArrayList<String>();
        images = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        players.add("Ashraful");
        images.add(R.drawable.a);
        players.add("Aftab");
        images.add(R.drawable.a);
        players.add("Tamim");
        images.add(R.drawable.a);
        Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getActivity(),players,images);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),players.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });*/
        //Using recycleview
        OurData ourData = new OurData();
        ourData.pic.add(R.drawable.aa);
        ourData.title.add("Ant");
        ourData.record.add(R.raw.a);

        ourData.pic.add(R.drawable.bb);
        ourData.title.add("Bat");
        ourData.record.add(R.raw.a);

        ourData.pic.add(R.drawable.cc);
        ourData.title.add("Cry");
        ourData.record.add(R.raw.a);

        ourData.pic.add(R.drawable.dd);
        ourData.record.add(R.raw.a);
        ourData.title.add("Dish");

        ourData.pic.add(R.drawable.ee);
        ourData.title.add("Elephant");
        ourData.record.add(R.raw.a);

        ourData.pic.add(R.drawable.ff);
        ourData.title.add("Fish");
        ourData.record.add(R.raw.a);

        ourData.pic.add(R.drawable.gg);
        ourData.record.add(R.raw.a);
        ourData.title.add("Goose");

        ourData.pic.add(R.drawable.hh);
        ourData.title.add("Hen");
        ourData.record.add(R.raw.a);

        ourData.pic.add(R.drawable.i);
        ourData.title.add("Ice-cream");
        ourData.record.add(R.raw.a);

        ourData.pic.add(R.drawable.jj);
        ourData.title.add("Jeep");
        ourData.record.add(R.raw.a);

        ourData.pic.add(R.drawable.kk);
        ourData.title.add("Kite");
        ourData.record.add(R.raw.a);

        ourData.pic.add(R.drawable.mm);
        ourData.title.add("Mother");
        ourData.record.add(R.raw.a);

        ourData.pic.add(R.drawable.nn);
        ourData.title.add("Nut");
        ourData.record.add(R.raw.a);

        ourData.pic.add(R.drawable.oo);
        ourData.record.add(R.raw.a);
        ourData.title.add("Orange");

        ourData.pic.add(R.drawable.pp);
        ourData.title.add("Price");
        ourData.record.add(R.raw.a);

        ourData.pic.add(R.drawable.qq);
        ourData.title.add("Quality");
        ourData.record.add(R.raw.a);

        ourData.pic.add(R.drawable.rr);
        ourData.title.add("Rock");
        ourData.record.add(R.raw.a);

        ourData.pic.add(R.drawable.ss);
        ourData.title.add("Six");
        ourData.record.add(R.raw.a);

        ourData.pic.add(R.drawable.tt);
        ourData.title.add("Time");
        ourData.record.add(R.raw.a);

        ourData.pic.add(R.drawable.uu);
        ourData.title.add("Use");
        ourData.record.add(R.raw.a);

        ourData.pic.add(R.drawable.vv);
        ourData.record.add(R.raw.a);
        ourData.title.add("Via");

        ourData.pic.add(R.drawable.ww);
        ourData.title.add("Watch");
        ourData.record.add(R.raw.a);

        ourData.pic.add(R.drawable.xx);
        ourData.title.add("Xylophone");
        ourData.record.add(R.raw.a);

        ourData.pic.add(R.drawable.yy);
        ourData.title.add("Yolk");
        ourData.record.add(R.raw.a);

        ourData.pic.add(R.drawable.zz);
        ourData.title.add("Zebra");
        ourData.record.add(R.raw.a);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.listRecyclerView);
        ListAdapter listAdapter = new ListAdapter();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        return view;
    }

/*    private void onViewCreated()
    {

    }*/
}
```

2nd fragment (capital letter):

```js
package com.example.adil.tabpen.Fragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.adil.tabpen.ListAdapter;
import com.example.adil.tabpen.OurData;
import com.example.adil.tabpen.R;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class TwoFragment extends Fragment {
    public TwoFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);

        OurData ourData = new OurData();
        ourData.pic.add(R.drawable.a);
        ourData.title.add("Apple");
        ourData.record.add(R.raw.a);

        ourData.pic.add(R.drawable.b);
        ourData.title.add("Ball");
        ourData.record.add(R.raw.a);

        ourData.pic.add(R.drawable.c);
        ourData.title.add("Cat");
        ourData.record.add(R.raw.a);

        ourData.pic.add(R.drawable.d);
        ourData.record.add(R.raw.a);
        ourData.title.add("Dog");

        ourData.pic.add(R.drawable.e);
        ourData.title.add("Egg");
        ourData.record.add(R.raw.a);

        ourData.pic.add(R.drawable.f);
        ourData.title.add("Flower");
        ourData.record.add(R.raw.a);

        ourData.pic.add(R.drawable.g);
        ourData.record.add(R.raw.a);
        ourData.title.add("Game");

        ourData.pic.add(R.drawable.h);
        ourData.title.add("Horse");
        ourData.record.add(R.raw.a);

        ourData.pic.add(R.drawable.i);
        ourData.title.add("Igloo");
        ourData.record.add(R.raw.a);

        ourData.pic.add(R.drawable.j);
        ourData.title.add("Jacket");
        ourData.record.add(R.raw.a);

        ourData.pic.add(R.drawable.k);
        ourData.title.add("Key");
        ourData.record.add(R.raw.a);

        ourData.pic.add(R.drawable.m);
        ourData.title.add("Mango");
        ourData.record.add(R.raw.a);

        ourData.pic.add(R.drawable.n);
        ourData.title.add("Net");
        ourData.record.add(R.raw.a);

        ourData.pic.add(R.drawable.o);
        ourData.record.add(R.raw.a);
        ourData.title.add("Owl");

        ourData.pic.add(R.drawable.p);
        ourData.title.add("Potato");
        ourData.record.add(R.raw.a);

        ourData.pic.add(R.drawable.q);
        ourData.title.add("Quit");
        ourData.record.add(R.raw.a);

        ourData.pic.add(R.drawable.r);
        ourData.title.add("Race");
        ourData.record.add(R.raw.a);

        ourData.pic.add(R.drawable.s);
        ourData.title.add("Shop");
        ourData.record.add(R.raw.a);

        ourData.pic.add(R.drawable.t);
        ourData.title.add("Tomato");
        ourData.record.add(R.raw.a);

        ourData.pic.add(R.drawable.u);
        ourData.title.add("Umbrella");
        ourData.record.add(R.raw.a);

        ourData.pic.add(R.drawable.v);
        ourData.record.add(R.raw.a);
        ourData.title.add("Vehicle");

        ourData.pic.add(R.drawable.w);
        ourData.title.add("Window");
        ourData.record.add(R.raw.a);

        ourData.pic.add(R.drawable.x);
        ourData.title.add("X-Ray");
        ourData.record.add(R.raw.a);

        ourData.pic.add(R.drawable.y);
        ourData.title.add("Yellow");
        ourData.record.add(R.raw.a);

        ourData.pic.add(R.drawable.z);
        ourData.title.add("Zoo");
        ourData.record.add(R.raw.a);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.listRecyclerView);
        ListAdapter listAdapter = new ListAdapter();
        recyclerView.setAdapter((listAdapter));
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        return view;
    }
}
```

1st fragment includes small letters, audio and a pic. 2nd fragment includes capital letters, audio and pic. My code works fine but I think I messed something. When I run the code I get both capital and small letters in both fragments. But my goal is to have capital letters in capital letter fragment and small letters in small letters fragment. I am unable to find that where should I change.

Comment: What do you mean by **1st fragment includes small letters** and **2nd fragment includes capital letters**

Comment: I am making an app which will have english alphabet(small and capital letter).Fragment one inserting small letters and fragment two inserting capital letters.

Comment: So you want *OurData.title.get(position)* to have both small and large letters depending on the circumstance?

Comment: I know i did mistake.But unable to find out where should I change.I am inserting all the data in same arraylist.So I am getting all letters in both fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
package com.example.adil.tabpen;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.adil.tabpen.Fragment.TwoFragment;
import com.example.adil.tabpen.OurData;

/**
 * Created by Adil on 10/2/2017.
 */

public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private boolean isUpperCase;
    public ListAdapter(boolean isUpperCase){
      this.isUpperCase = isUpperCase;
    } 
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        return new ListViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        ((ListViewHolder) holder).bindView(position);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return OurData.title.size();
    }

    private class ListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
    {
        private TextView text;
        private ImageView image;
        private ImageButton button;

        public ListViewHolder(View itemview)
        {
            super(itemview);
            text = (TextView) itemview.findViewById(R.id.textF);
            image = (ImageView) itemview.findViewById(R.id.imageF);
            button = (ImageButton) itemview.findViewById(R.id.button);
            itemview.setOnClickListener(this);
        }


        public void bindView(final int position)
        {
            text.setText(isUpperCase ? OurData.title.get(position).toUpperCase() : OurData.title.get(position).toLowerCase());
            image.setImageResource(OurData.pic.get(position));
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {

                    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(v.getContext(), OurData.record.get(position));
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                }
            });
        }

        public void onClick (View view)
        {

        }


    }
}
```

And then when creating the adapter you should either

`ListAdapter listAdapter = new ListAdapter(true);` to get capital letters only or
`ListAdapter listAdapter = new ListAdapter(false);` for small letters